# spring oauth2 how to get a new refresh token every time

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

When I call refresh token the web service returns a new access token and the old refresh token because the access token has not yet expired. Is there any configuration that when I call refresh token this web service return me a new access token and a **new** refresh token?

Answer (score 1):

Spring can be configured not to reuse refresh tokens - by default it reuses -, this should solve the issue.

```
@Configuration
public class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer configurer) throws Exception {
        configurer.reuseRefreshTokens(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use AOP to invalidate token by removing old one, or change its validity time, before generate new one,but if you do so then you are going to invalidate all refresh tokens used by other clients.

Comment: Is there any way on spring security oauth2 to issue a one time use refresh token and refresh the refresh token along with the access token??I have an android application on which the client needs to authenticate to this oauth2 server and then he doesn't want to login again after the first time authentication.If the refresh token expires then again he need to provide the username and passwor, i need to avoid this situation..

Comment: you can make your refresh token invalidity date is too far then intercept generated token to invalidate the refresh token and let it generate new one with the too far invalidity date.

Comment: How  can i invalidate the refresh token and generate a new refresh token??

Comment: based on your TokenStore, for example in my case it was DataSource TokenStore so I was deleting row from DB.